# What do you qualify a video that keeps pausing?

Tags: word-request

I know buffering is used, but it implies that the video is getting downloaded still, but what about a video that's already downloaded and keeps pausing for some reason. What adjective would you use to qualify such a video?

Comment: You can say the video doesn't play smoothly. I think "stutter" is also used sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the adjective [choppy](https://www.google.com/search?q=choppy+video).

Example of use in https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/play-video-smoothly-pc:

> Watching choppy video playback is like sailing choppy waters: rough, frightening, and may lead to nausea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the adjective [jerky](https://www.google.com/search?q=jerky+video). Example of use in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17999845/395857):

> The video plays but it's really jerky.